# Mac app to switch between /etc/hosts files, how to allow access?

Tags: swift, macos, hosts

I'm making a small mac menu app to quickly switch between hosts files I have, in order to switch between my network environments.

```
try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/etc/hosts__ENV_1"), 
to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/etc/hosts"))
```

The above returns `nil`, I'm assuming due to lack of privileges.

How to provide the privileges to replace `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Look at the error instead of turning the useful error message into a `nil` using `try?` and you'll know for sure if the error's caused by the lack of privileges or anything else.

Comment: `"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 257` so it's definitely due to lack of privileges. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Is your app sandboxed or not?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm new Mac development. I've exported the `.app` file and placed it in `Applications`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify files like `/etc/hosts` which are writable only by root, you will need to use a privileged helper tool, install it using `SMJobBless()`, and communicate with it via XPC.

Apple's [EvenBetterAuthorizationSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code demonstrates the recommended way to do this, along with providing a small sample library that you can use. It is in Objective-C, but Objective-C code is not difficult to integrate into a Swift project. (One of these days, I'll publish my own Swift-native version of this, but it currently needs cleaning up before I'll be proud of the source.)

Comment: I'll give it ago, thank you. Will it ask the user to input a password?

Comment: @thedp They will need to enter a password to install the tool. After that, it's up to you, but I would recommend requiring a password each time it's used, as otherwise it's a security risk since someone other app could access your helper. Whatever you do, be sure to limit the helper's functionality as much as possible to make it do the bare minimum of what you need (i.e., hard-code it to move `/etc/hosts__ENV_1` to `/etc/hosts`, not to move arbitrary files to arbitrary places) to reduce the fallout if someone manages to gain unauthorized access to the helper.

Comment: Do I need a Developer Certificate to use the privileged helper tool?

Comment: @thedp I do believe you'll need the app and tool both to be signed using a Developer ID certificate.

Comment: I see. Is there any other way to make my app write to `/etc/hosts`? Thanks again :)

Comment: @thedp Using a privileged helper tool is the proper way to do it.