# SwiftUI: How to access terminal with MacOS app?

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, localhost

So I have this button that lets me run **/usr/bin/say** in the terminal, which works just fine. But when I try to change the **executableURL** variable, so I run **sudo nano /private/etc/hosts** instead, I get this error [image]
So my question is, how can I access the terminal through my macOS app and run **sudo nano /private/etc/hosts**?

```
 Button(action: {
          let executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/say")
    //    let executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "sudo nano /private/etc/hosts")
    
           self.isRunning = true
           do {
               try Process.run(executableURL,
                               arguments: ["Hello World"],
                               terminationHandler: { _ in self.isRunning = false })
               } catch{
                     print(error)
               }
                    
            }) {
                Text("Say")
            }
```

**EDIT:**

By using this arguments                                         `arguments: ["-c", "echo myPassword | sudo -S -- sh -c \"echo \"127.0.0.1www.apple.com \" >> /etc/hosts\""]`
line and this path `URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh")` I was able to append to the hosts file.

A problem that I'm having is that I was able to append the things you see in the picture(not line 1) but for some reason nothing is appended anymore when I try to do the same as before. Which is a big problem. I think I have to create a new line after appending something. Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the App Sandbox. It should work then.

EDIT:

```
    let executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh")

    self.isRunning = true
    do {
        try Process.run(executableURL,
                        // Replace userpassword with the user's password and yourline with the line you want to append to the file. (If you really want to use nano, you can replace echo... >> ... with nano /private/etc/hosts)
                        arguments: ["-c", "echo password | sudo -S -- sh -c \"echo test >> /etc/hosts\""],
                        terminationHandler: { _ in self.isRunning = false })
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what would this do? @techrisdev

Comment: When you disable the App Sandbox, you can access all Files on the System (and use things like the Accessibility API). The problem with disabling it is that you can’t publish your App to the App Store. Apple will not accept it.

Comment: You could also look into [Security-Scoped Bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference/asset/media-rep_element/bookmark/enabling_security-scoped_bookmark_and_url_access?changes=_9)

Comment: Well if disabling the App Sandbox prohibits me from publishing my project, then I don't think that's the way I'm gonna go. I tried looking a bit into Security-Scoped Bookmarks but couldn't really get a good understanding of it, can you explain what it does? @techrisdev

Comment: Honestly, I never really looked into Security-Scoped Bookmarks. I think you can present a NSOpenPanel to the user, let him choose a path and then save the opened path as a Bookmark which you can access later.

Comment: Also, /private/etc/hosts is a file, not a command (not executable). Maybe it isn't even a Sandbox issue (I also tried out accessing the file with FileManager, and it worked fine). What do you want to do with the file?

Comment: Well my goal is to run sudo nano /private/etc/hosts, which opens the file. I then want to add something to it. All of this should happen in the background without the user actually seeing the terminal. How did you access the file? Did you do it through a macOS project, or did you simply write it in the terminal? @techrisdev

Comment: I used a macOS project. I don't think nano will work, why don't you append a line using `echo "Your Line" >> /private/etc/hosts`? See my edited answer, it works fine. I think the problem was that you didn't provide the full path to the commands (/usr/bin/sudo...). I changed your code a little bit by executing zsh for easier readability. Unfortunately, I don't think you have permission to execute sudo in a Sandboxed app.

Comment: When I use your code and have the arguments like this, `arguments: ["-c", "echo myPassword | sudo -S echo 127.0.0.1 www.apple.com /private/etc/hosts"]` I get the following in my xcode terminal `Password:127.0.0.1 www.apple.com /private/etc/hosts`. Is this supposed to happen? If so, why cant I see the changes in the hosts file, when I check it? @techrisdev

Comment: Notice in the arguments i have not added the `>>`since it give me this in the code terminal `zsh:1: permission denied: /private/etc/hosts` any ideas on what to do? Would really appreciate it @techrisdev

Comment: The ">>" sign is necessary. It means "append". After further investigation I found out that the file is probably protected by [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). Can you edit the file in a normal Terminal (with sudo nano or sudo vim)? Try really overwriting the file (saving).

Comment: Nevermind, I can write to the file with SIP enabled. Well, by now I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Sandboxing. I wrote a little script that checks if one could write to the file. It works fine when running as root (sudo -S...) and Sandboxing disabled, but when I enable Sandboxing it stops working. Because in your Sandbox, you have your own Container, you cannot access files other than some of the files in the user's home directory.

Comment: Okay lets say I am okay with disabling Sandbox, what should do now? Because when I add the `>>` I get the `permission denied:...` message I mentioned earlier. Btw how should I disable Sandbox? I'm not sure I'm doing it right, all I do is click the "x" by  `app sandbox` in "Signing & Capabilities" @techrisdev

Comment: To disable the Sandbox, go to the YourApp.entitlements file in your Xcode project, select App Sandbox and change the Key to NO. Then, it should work. If you're running as root (sudo). Also, make sure that you replaced "userpassword" with your/the user's password.

Comment: So I disabled Sandbox and my arguments look like this **arguments: ["-c", "echo myCode | sudo -S echo 127.0.0.1 www.apple.com >> /private/etc/hosts"]** But i still get this `zsh:1: permission denied: /private/etc/hosts`any ideas? @techrisdev

Comment: Try doing `echo "127.0.0.1 www.apple.com" >> /private/etc/hosts >> ...` (with quotes).

Comment: But wouldnt that create a "" inside another "" @techrisdev

Comment: Is this what you mean?  **arguments: ["-c", "echo password | sudo -S echo "127.0.0.1 www.apple.com" >> /private/etc/hosts"]** if so, I get this error when doing it `Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected element type 'Array<String>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'String')`

Comment: you need to escape the quotes with \

Comment: You can also use single quotes.

Comment: So this is the correct way to do it? **arguments: ["-c", "echo password | sudo -S echo \"127.0.0.1 www.apple.com\" >> /private/etc/hosts"]** @techrisdev

Comment: Yes, try it out.

Comment: I tried it out, but im still getting the same output. **zsh:1: permission denied: /private/etc/hosts**. I think it is the ">>" messing it up @techrisdev

Comment: That's weird. If you edit the file in a normal Terminal, it works?

Comment: Yeah, if i write `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and then my password in the terminal, I can edit the hosts file @techrisdev

Comment: Have you tried actually overwriting (saving) the file?

Comment: Yes, I have opened the hosts file and edited and saved it multiple times, and it works every time. All through the terminal ofc @techrisdev

Comment: Ok, then, it is an issue with using sudo in the App. You may need to use SMJobBless(), which I never used. You also will need to have the Sandbox disabled, to access the file.

Comment: Okay, how should i go about doing that? I have never heard of SMJobBless() @techrisdev

Comment: I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091887/mac-app-to-switch-between-etc-hosts-files-how-to-allow-access). It is almost the same as your's, only that you want to edit the file it self and the person that asked the other question wants to copy another file to the path.

Comment: So i read the post, but im not entirely sure what I should do next? @techrisdev

Comment: Sorry, for me the method we talked about before works. I created a file where only the root has rights to and tried it out. It works fine.

Comment: Ok, it's a problem with the /private/etc/hosts file. I created a file with the exact same rights, it works, but the hosts file doesn't.

Comment: So what should be done about this? @techrisdev

Comment: I think I found the answer: https://superuser.com/a/538763

Comment: These arguments should work: `arguments: ["-c", "echo password | sudo -S -- sh -c \"echo test >> /etc/hosts\""]`

Comment: Okay so where should i write the things i want to add to the file? And its still with the same fileURLWithPath, right?  @techrisdev

Comment: Replace "test" with the characters you want to add (with quotes around them).

Comment: I updated my initial post with some feedback on the use of `arguments: ["-c", "echo password | sudo -S -- sh -c \"echo test >> /etc/hosts\""]` @techrisdev

Comment: I think i found the soloution, i think i basically have to create a new line after each append. But how can I do that? @techrisdev

Comment: \n after every append: `\"echo 'youline\n' >> /etc/hosts\"`

Comment: Okay thanks I will try it out but in the meantime. How can I remove a line from the hosts file, instead of appending to it? @techrisdev

Comment: You can use `sed -i '' '1d' /private/etc/hosts` to delete a line of the text file, where 1 is the line you want to delete. You could also use $ instead of a number if you want to delete the last line of the file.

Comment: I will try it out once i get some time on my hands, but I'm not quite sure where the line should be written. Is it supposed to be a part of the `arguments line`or how should I use it? @techrisdev

Comment: An example: `arguments: ["-c", "echo myPassword | sudo -S -- sh -c \"sed -i '' '1d' /etc/hosts\""]`

Comment: ahh yes okay i see, And would it be possible to delete multiple lines at the same time? If so, how? @techrisdev

Comment: Just like in a normal shell (with ;): `arguments: ["-c", "echo myPassword | sudo -S -- sh -c \"sed -i '' '1d' /etc/hosts; sed -i '' '2d' /etc/hosts\""]`. Another option would be using the ; character directly in sed: `arguments: ["-c", "echo myPassword | sudo -S -- sh -c \"sed -i '' '1d;2d' /etc/hosts\""]`. That would look cleaner.

Comment: I tried deleting multiple lines simultaneously, and it works as it should. But is it also possible to append multiple lines at the same time the same way? If not, is there then another way to do it? @techrisdev

Comment: Again with the semicolon character: `arguments: ["-c", "echo myPassword | sudo -S -- sh -c \"echo 'line' >> /etc/hosts; echo 'second line' >> /etc/hosts\""]`. You could also use the newline character: `echo 'first line\nsecond line'`

Comment: I see how this would work when I know how many "things" i want to append. But what if I don't know how many "things" i want to append? @techrisdev

Comment: Use a for-loop in Swift and execute the Process every time.

Comment: I tried using Foreach, but when doing so I keep getting this error `Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'` In the Foreach I have the code you provided in your answer. (Obviously with the modifications we have talked about) @techrisdev

Comment: ForEach is a part of SwiftUI. You need to use the standard Swift for-loop.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you know if it is possible to delete everything below a certain line in the hosts file. Instead of deleting single lines? @techrisdev