# Write to /etc/hosts on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, permissions, hosts

I want to change my `/etc/hosts` file om MacOS.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/etc/hosts");
newContentString.write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8);
```

I get this error, not entirely unexpected ;)

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “hosts” in the folder “etc”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/etc/hosts, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000112c630 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}
```

I can read the file, just want to know how save a string to the `/etc/hosts` file.

- MacOS
- Sandbox is off
- SwiftUI
- Works when using "/Users/myname/Desktop/hosts"

Comment: If you do this from the command line you need to use sudo so you don’t have the correct access rights  when doing it from your app.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091887/mac-app-to-switch-between-etc-hosts-files-how-to-allow-access) can be useful